# According to language change currency of zencart

Tags: google-translate, zen-cart, google-shopping-api

Am working on a zen cart project, I have used Google language converter to change the language of site,

now the project demand is if

"customer is in spanish google shopping and he click on my site product it take him to the product page displayed in euros and spanish without them doing anything".

Now I have some specific question to ask

How can we set the currency according to language, b'cz zen cart didn't provide this?

Is it possible to achieve the same requirement?

Thanks

and if yes Please suggest me the way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are not using inbuilt multi-language facility so It's very difficult to get solution.

This can be possible in two different ways.

1. First of all maintain relation between language and currency. create/add special div where you show price in html `<div class="randomPrice">$10.00</div>`. By adding special div you will get all instance of price in loaded html. Now on change of language by Google language update all special div with updated currency.
2. Use default multi-language facility and maintain relation between language and currency. when user change language update currency session accordingly.

Comment: Many Thanks for the solution..but need some more answer how can we set the language of google translator automatically..is there any way to set default lang on page load? and the second one is about the first way you have provided in this case how can we change the currency according to lang.?

Comment: Zen cart manage language and currency info in session, you need to work around this two session. let say if you implement first solution then you need to create js function which set lang variable on page load. if someone change language by google lanauge tool then you need to call another function which is change value of  <div class="randomPrice">$10.00</div> by mathematics calculation (depend on currency conversation rate). if you select second option then you just need to set currency session as per language selection